# How to install development tools when Ruby compiled from source

Tags: windows, installation, ruby

I have Windows 8, and I need to install Ruby 2.1.2 for a project. I followed [these instructions](http://madcoderspeak.blogspot.com/2009/06/how-to-compile-ruby-from-source-on.html). I unzipped the source into `C:\Ruby2.1.2\src\`, ran `nmake` in `C:\Ruby2.1.2\build\`, and ran `nmake install` with the destination folder `C:\Ruby2.1.2\bin\`. When I installed Ruby 2.1.2, I got a number of errors like this:

```
configuring zlib
Failed to configure zlib. It will not be installed.
```

This happened for dbm, fiddle, gdbm, openssl, pty, readline, syslog, tk, tk/tkutil, and zlib. However, the tests in `nmake test` all pass.

I already have Ruby 2.0.0 and 1.9.3, but I need 2.0.0 for other projects. I am using [pik 0.3.0.pre](https://github.com/vertiginous/pik) to manage the dependecies, and it seems to be working for 2.0.0 and 1.9.3.

However if I switch to Ruby 2.1.2 run `gem install` for anything, I get:

```
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
        cannot load such file -- zlib
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

After some digging, I tried navigating to C:\Ruby2.1.2\src\ruby-2.1.2\ext\zlib and running `ruby extconf.rb` The error I got for that was:

```
checking for deflateReset() in z.lib... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby2.1.2/bin/usr/bin/ruby
        --with-zlib-dir
        --with-zlib-include
        --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
        --with-zlib-lib
        --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
        --with-zlib
        --without-zlib
C:/Ruby2.1.2/bin/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from C:/Ruby2.1.2/bin/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:541:in `try_link0'
        from C:/Ruby2.1.2/bin/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:556:in `try_link'
        from C:/Ruby2.1.2/bin/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:742:in `try_func'
        from C:/Ruby2.1.2/bin/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:973:in `block in have_library'
        from C:/Ruby2.1.2/bin/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:918:in `block in checking_for'
        from C:/Ruby2.1.2/bin/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
        from C:/Ruby2.1.2/bin/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
        from C:/Ruby2.1.2/bin/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block in postpone'
        from C:/Ruby2.1.2/bin/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
        from C:/Ruby2.1.2/bin/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:347:in `postpone'
        from C:/Ruby2.1.2/bin/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:917:in `checking_for'
        from C:/Ruby2.1.2/bin/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:968:in `have_library'
        from extconf.rb:13:in `block in <main>'
        from extconf.rb:13:in `each'
        from extconf.rb:13:in `find'
        from extconf.rb:13:in `<main>'
```

It looks like I need to install development tools. But [the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11559912/issues-installing-ruby-and-rails-and-devkit-on-windows-7-x64-fix-needed) [only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10862695/trying-to-install-dev-kit-for-ruby-in-windows-7-but-fails) [sources](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubyinstaller/gTYXhk7_0Kw) [I found](http://rubylearning.com/blog/how-do-i-install-a-ruby-gem-with-native-extensions-on-windows/) about installing development tools directed me to the RubyInstaller which doesn't have Ruby 2.1.2 yet.

I also tried installing zlib separately and running `ruby extconf.rb --with-zlib-dir="C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32"`, but that gave me the second error again.

Another thing I tried was running `gem install zlib -- --with-zlib-dir="C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32"`, but that gave me the first error again.

**How do I install development tools so I can get rubygems to work?**

Comment: I have the same issue :( Would love to find the solution. One hint I got was the [rake tasks](https://github.com/larsch/rubyinstaller-luislavena/blob/master/recipes/dependencies/zlib.rake) from the ruby-installer, but all it appears to be doing is putting the zlib1.dll into the src folder of Ruby. I did not have the time to test this thoroughly out yet however.

Answer (score 1):

Eva, Were you able to solve your problem?

I'm doing exact same thing as you (using Windows 8.1), and I finally got zlib installed.

1) I downloaded zlib128-dll.zip from http://zlib.net and unzipped the contents to a directory (e.g., c:\zlib).

2) Then following some hints from this post (https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4421852), I created these dirs off of my c:\ruby-build\usr directory:

```
zlib
zlib\include
zlib\lib
```

3) Then I copied some files from my C:\zlib directories to my c:\ruby-build\usr directories:

```
*.h files (both) from C:\zlib\include to c:\ruby-build\usr\zlib\include 
zdll.lib from C:\zlib\lib to c:\ruby-build\usr\zlib\lib. 
zlib1.dll *AS* zlib.dll from C:\zlib to both c:\ruby-build\usr\zlib\lib and c:\ruby-build\usr\bin 
    (not sure which one or both are necessary).
```

4) Then from a VS 2012 Native Tools Command Window, I naviagted to C:\ruby-2.1.2\ext\zlib and executed:

```
\ruby-build\usr\bin\ruby extconf.rb --with-zlib-dir=c:/ruby-build/usr/zlib
```

5) Then nmake, followed by nmake install, and voila, I zlib was finally installed.

Let me know if you any questions about my steps.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby includes several libraries, part of their *standard library* (stdlib) that depends on external libraries, like Zlib, OpenSSL, FFI, just to mention a few.

In order to build Ruby, you need to make those libraries available to Ruby, so it can compile against them.

At RubyInstaller, we solved that issue by building the dependencies as packages and using them during Ruby compilation.

In your case, appears you're using Visual Studio, which means you cannot use the binary packages provided by RubyInstaller as the runtime dependencies of those differ.

If usage of Visual Studio is really not a requirement, then perhaps you can use RubyInstaller recipes to generate a local package of Ruby 2.1.x:

```
cd rubyinstaller
rake ruby21 DKVER=mingw64-32-4.7.2 LOCAL=C:\path\to\ruby\source
```

This tells RubyInstaller recipes to use `mingw64` compiler (GCC) 32bits version 4.7.2 and use the local source checkout pointed in `LOCAL`

All this is covered in RubyInstaller's [README](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/blob/master/README.txt)

If you need further assistance, please reach out to RubyInstaller's [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rubyinstaller)